# Null space of linear operator in topological space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a topological vector space and $\phi \in V'$. I want to prove that if the interior of $\mathrm{ker}~\phi$ is nonempty, then $\phi = 0$.

Since no metric on $V$ is given, balls are not defined. Otherwise I would have taken a look at $\phi(x+\varepsilon v)$ for $v \in V$, $\varepsilon > 0$ small and $x \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{ker}~\phi)$. But I don't know if this reasoning is somehow applicable to a topological space.

Comment: Just replace "ball" with "neighbourhood of $0$". Further needed modifications in the reasoning should be very small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be a neighbourhood of $0$ small enough to be contained in $\text{ker}(\phi)$. We want to prove that there is a basis of vectors $\{v_i\}$ contained in $I$. To do so, take a basis $\{b_i\}$ of $V$, and consider its image through the function $f(k,v)=k\cdot v$. Since this function is continuous, and $\forall_v f(0,v)=0$, it follows that there's a $k_i:k_iv_i\in I$. Thus we have obtained a basis $\{k_iv_i\}$ of $V$ contained in $I$, and so $\phi\equiv 0$

Comment: But what if $\dim V = \infty$ meaning that there is no basis?

Comment: There's a basis for every vector space, provided you have the axiom of choice

Comment: Okay thank you!

Comment: No basis is needed. Once you have a neighborhood $N$ of $0$ included in a vector subspace $S$, then, by continuity, every vector $v$ has a multiple $kv$ in $N$, with $k>0$, and so $v$ itself is in $S$.